# How does the Integration Tier interface with the Business Tier?

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, ejb, n-tier-architecture

I need some advice on designing an "Integration Tier" of an N-Tiered system in Java.  This tier is responsible for persisting and retrieving data for the "Business Tier" (located on a separate server).  I'm new to J2EE and I've read a few books and blogs.  The alphabet soup of technology acronyms is confusing me so I have a handful of questions.

First, what I have so far:  I'm using JPA (via Hibernate) for persisting and retrieving data to a database.  I made my data access objects EJBs and plan on deploying to an application server (JBoss) which makes transactions easier (they're at the function level of my DAOs) and I don't have to worry about getting a handle to an EntityManager (dependency injection).  Here's an example of what things look like:

```
@Entity
class A{
  @Id
  Long id;
  @OneToMany
  List<B> setOfBs = new ArrayList<B>;
}

@Entity
class B{
  @Id
  Long id;
}

@Remote
public interface ADAO{
  public A getAById(Long id);
}

@Stateless
class ADAOImpl implements ADAO{
  @PersistenceContext
  EntityManager em;

  public A getAById(Long id){ ... }
}
```

My question: How should the Business Tier exchange data with the Integration Tier.  I've read up on RESTful services, and they seem simple enough.  My concern is performance when the frequency of gets and sets increases (HTTP communication doesn't seem particularly fast).  Another option is RMI.  My DAOs are already EJBs.  Could I just have the Business Tier access them directly (via JNDI)?  If so, what happens if the @OneToMany link in the example above are lazily loaded?

For example if the Business Tier does something like the following:

```
Context context = new InitialContext(propertiesForIntegrationTierLookup);
ADAOImpl aDao = (ADAOImpl) context.lookup("something");
A myA = aDao.getAById(0);
int numberOfBs = myA.setOfBs.size();
```

If the setOfBs list is loaded lazily, when the Business Tier (on a separate server) accesses the list, is the size correct?  Does the list somehow get loaded correctly through the magic of EJBs?  If not (which I expect), what's the solution?

Sorry for the long post.  Like I said I'm new to J2EE and I've read enough to get the general idea, but I need help on fitting the pieces together.

Answer (score 0):

When you call size() on lazy collection, it gets initialized, so you'll always get correct size no matter which interface you're using - Remote or Local.

Another situation is when you're trying to use JPA classes as data transfer objects (DTO) and request them via Remote interface. I don't remember any lazy initialization issues here, cause prior to transmission all objects have to be serialized (with lazy collections initialized) on server side. As a result, the whole object graph is passed over network, which might cause serious cpu and network overheads. In addition, for deserialization to be possible, you will have to share JPA classes with remote app. And that's where and how 'EJB magic' ends :)

So, once remote calls are possible, I'd suggest to start thinking of data transfer strategy and non-JPA data transfer objects as additional data layer. In my case, I've annotated DTO classes for XML binding (JAXB) and reused them in web-services.

Comment: I took your input and spent the last few days studying up on EE design patterns.  It looks like I have two options for transferring data between the Integration tier and the Business tier: DTOs or REST.  

Using DTOs seems like it would introduce a lot of extra code on the Integration tier (convert from Doman class A to DTO B, etc), but the DTOs could be reused in the Business tier.  

REST would be easy for the Integration tier, but the Business tier would have to do the grunt work of parsing and performance may be an issue.  Neither solution seems perfect.  

Is there a third option?

Comment: Whoops, I didn't mean REST.  The two options would be either DTOs or some text-based method, like XML.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: If you are using an "Integration Layer" approach, the things you should be integrating should be loosely coupled services, following SOA principles.

This means you should not be allowing remote calls to methods on entities that could be making calls to the framework under the lid on another server. If you do this, you are really building a tightly coupled distributed application and you will have to worry about the lazy loading problems and the scope of the persistence context. If you want that, you might like to consider extended persistence contexts http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/tutorial/extended_pc/extended.html.

You have talked about a "business tier", but JPA does not provide a business tier. It provides entities and allows CRUD operations, but these are typically not business operations. a "RegisterUser" operation is not simply a question of persisting a "User" entity. Your DAO layer may offer a higher level of operation, but DAOs are typically used to put a thin layer over the database, but it is still very data centric.

A better approach is to define business service type operations and make those the services that you expose. You might want another layer on top of your DAO or you might want to have one layer (convert your DAO layer).

You business layer should call flush and handle any JPA exceptions and hide all of that from the caller.

The issue of how to transfer your data remains. In many cases the parameters of your business service requests will be similar to your JPA entities, but I think you will notice that often there are sufficient differences that you want to define new DTOs. For example, a "RegisterUser" business operation might update both the "User" and "EmailAddresses" table. The User table might include a "createdDate" property which is not part of the "RegisterUser" operation, but is set to the current date.

For creating DTOs, you might like to look at Project Lombok.

To copy the DTO to the Entity, you can use Apache Commons BeanUtils (e.g., PropertyUtils.copyProperties) to do a lot of the leg work, which works if the property names are the same.

Personally, I don't see the point in XML in this case, unless you want to totally decouple your implementations.